# When is the (Fenchel-Rockafellar) duality gap strictly positive?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, duality-theorems

In optimization, there is a notion of the [duality gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_gap), $\Delta$ which is always positive $\Delta\geq 0$. The condition $\Delta=0$, called *strong duality*, is sometimes quite convenient in the analysis of optimization problems. There are a lot of sufficient conditions (e.g., Slater's condition) which guarantee $\Delta = 0$ (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization))), and there are also many examples (in optimization books) where the aforementioned sufficient conditions fail but $\Delta=0$ still holds.

However, I am less familiar with examples or classes of problems which are *known* to possess a **strictly positive duality gap** $\Delta>0$. So, with this question I am hoping we can compile a list of interesting examples which demonstrate this behavior (with particular attention to properties of the functions, such as convexity and/or smoothness).

Comment: There are examples of linear programs with $\Delta = +\infty$.

Comment: @daw interesting! if you could please point toward a reference or further explain, that would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

An example is **interior point methods with logarithmic barrier**. For reference, cf. Boyd & Vandenberghe *"Convex Optimization"* chap. $11$ "Interior-point methods" with its $70$ pages on the subject.

The goal is to find $x \in \mathbb R ^n$ that minimizes $f_0(x)$,
subject to constraints $f_i(x) \le 0, i=1\dots m$, and $Ax=b$,
where $f_0$ and $f_i: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ are convex and twice continuously differentiable,
$A$ is a $p \times n$ matrix, $p \lt n$, with rank $p$,
and $b \in \mathbb R ^p$.
(And we assume the problem is strictly feasible: $\exists x$ satisfying $\forall i, f_i(x) \le 0$, and $Ax=b$).

The method adds a logarithmic barrier term $\Phi(x) = - \sum_{i=1}^m \log(-f_i(x))$ to the objective function $tf_0(x)$.
($t$ is a parameter which $\to \infty$. Usually people define the new objective function as $f_0(x) + \mu \Phi(x)$, where $\mu \to 0$. This is equivalent, but Boyd & Vandenberghe chose this because it makes some proofs easier, when differentiating on $t$).
The method principle is to solve the new optimization problem ($tf_0(x) + \Phi(x)$), for some value of $t$, with Newton's method, then grow $t$ and repeat, using the previous optimum as initial point for Newton's method.

A very nice property of logarithmic barriers (and only this class of functions) is that the **duality gap** associated to optima $x^*$ and $\lambda^*$ for a specific value of $t$, is simply $m/t$. It depends only upon the number of constraints and the value of parameter $t$, not upon the problem other characteristics.
One consequence is that, contrary to simplex method (for linear problems) where the optimum is reached after a finite number of steps, here the number of steps is in theory infinite. But in practice, a sufficient precision is reached faster than with simplex method.

Note that in the original problem, Slater's condition holds, so the duality gap is $0$. It is only on problems with added logarithmic barrier that the duality gap is $m/t \gt 0$, with this quantity $\to 0$ when $t \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the linear programming problem
$$
\min c^Tx
$$
subject to
$$
Ax=b, \ x\ge0.
$$
Its dual is given by
$$
\max b^Ty
$$
subject to
$$
A^Ty \le c.
$$
With the choices
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1}, \quad
b = \pmatrix{0 \\1 }, \quad
c = \pmatrix{-1 \\ -1}
$$
the primal and dual problems have no feasible points. Hence, the duality gap is infinite.

To see this, note that $b$ is not in the image of $A$, and that the condition
$A^Ty\le c$ is equivalent to $|y_1+y_2|\le -1$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wonder if there are also examples with a nonzero gap for which both primal and dual have nonempty feasible regions?

Comment: This is not possible for linear programs.